# remove parts of numbers in a string

Tags: python, arrays

The question is the following:

```
Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.
 
    summer_69([1, 3, 5]) --> 9
    summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) --> 9
    summer_69([2, 1, 6, 9, 11]) --> 14
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove numbers starting from 6 towards 9 in the array, and then return the sum of the others. But how can I do like that? Is there a function that serves this kind of role? Thank you!

This is the code I came up with partially (it doesn't work for sure):

```
def summer_69(arr):
    if 6 not in arr:
        return sum(arr)
    else:
        new_arr = arr.remove() #I'm trying to remove numbers between 6 and 9
        return sum(new_arr)
```

Comment: If you want something builtin to Python [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) helps you do what you want.

Comment: `new_arr = arr.remove()` the `list.remove` method *works in place* and returns `None`, so `new_arr` is going to be `None`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```py
def summer_69(arr:list)->int:
    result = 0  # Final sum of numbers not 6,7, 8, or 9
    if not 6 in arr: # If no six in array
        return sum(arr)

    encountered_six = False # A flag set when a six is first encountered
    for number in arr: # Iterate the input list
        if not encountered_six and number != 6: # Haven't hit a six yet, and current number isn't six
            result += number

        elif number == 6: # Set flag to ignore numbers until a 9 is reached
            encountered_six =True
        
        elif encountered_six and number == 9:
            encountered_six = False # Reset the flag to False and keep summing values
        
        else: # Encountered a six and not yet hit a nine, ignore the number
            continue

    return result
```

### Solution Explanation

The idea for this is to set a boolean flag once the six is hit, and only set it back to false once the next nine is found. Then during those steps in the iteration, ignore all values and continue the loop. Any other loop iterations are summed, and as you had in your original code if there are no sixes, just return the whole sum.

### Assumptions

You mentioned updating in place, but the question seems to suggest just returning the sum. If you need to return the list with the values stripped as well, then you can also create a new list variable outside the loop, and only append the current number to the result list during the first `if` block and return the sum and the result list after the iteration.

### Additional steps

You may want to do error catching, like if the list has types that aren't `int`, and if the list is empty etc.

Comment: This isn't actually what the function is supposed to do. (And anyway, you would probably use something like `not (6 <= number <= 9)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I reread the comment at the top and see what you mean, I will adjust the answer

Comment: Yeah, the examples weren't good for disambiguating

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, they were picked to be that way it seems. Answer is updated with a naive (and slightly inefficient) approach that should be reasonable. There are probably better fancier solutions with `ittertools`, but it should work and be relatively readable.

Answer (score 0):

if the target output is the sum of the elements of the list minus the [6,7,8,9]:

```
def filterSum(arry):
    sum=0
    for j in range(len(arry)):
        if arry[j]not in [6,7,8,9]:
            sum+=arry[j]
    return sum
```